# Url with 2 parameters / rewriting in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I host my website on a godaddy webserver and i try to use .htaccess file to rewrite some urls but it doesn't work. Help would be very appreciated.

Basically I would like to replace an url like:

https://www.example.com/photographers/photographer.php?id=1&name=john-doe

in:

https://www.example.com/photographer/1/john-doe

Parameter 1 is: id / Parameter 2 is: name

Obviously I would like also my server to redirect internally in the opposite way.

I tried a lot of combinations but with the rewriterule but none is working. For example I tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^photographer/(\d+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/?$   photographers/photographer.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: If you tried "a lot of combinations", could you please share the most promising and tell us what _exactly_ did not work for you? Because otherwise we would only repeat all the answers already given on SO for questions like that...

Comment: I add an example of what I tries in the question. Thank you.